# Окно Find in Path не сдвигается за границы экрана

Tags: android-studio, search

После обновления `Android Studio` до `3.3` перестало сдвигаться окно `Find in Path` (`Ctrl+Shift+F/R`) за границы монитора. То есть окно "заперто" границами монитора. Влево и вверх при этом, что интересно, сдвигается, но это не очень удобно.

В списке обновлений, в настройках или вообще на просторах Интернета обнаружить способ сдвигать окно вправо/вниз не удалось.